# python -- manually install downloaded module without admin rights

Tags: python, installation, pip, spyder

I am trying to install the python package `us` without admin privileges.

I have tried `pip install us` in Anaconda prompt to no avail.

I have also tried the suggestion listed here: [Install python modules on windows without admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490700/install-python-modules-on-windows-without-admin-rights)--didn't work.

I have now downloaded the files from the site https://pypi.org/project/us/ to my desktop and need to know how to install the package from here.

I am using the Spyder IDE and Python 3.7.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: does it work if you install pip itself with conda and then try `pip install us` again?

Comment: do you mean `conda install pip` in the anaconda prompt? `conda install pip` times out: 'connection to repo.anaconda.com timed out'.

Comment: pip might still be trying to install systemwide. if you install pip with conda, subsequent use of pip might be the new version of pip within the conda environment. If that makes sense. If you are on linux you could check this  `which pip`, `conda install pip`, `which pip` again. If I am right first `which` will point to systemwide. Second will point to the new install in your conda environment

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Try to look an the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment I think this communicates the idea of using the pip inside conda environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this on the daily and if I understand what you are saying you are doing it right. If `pip install us` in command prompt or shell (if you are using Windows OS) doesn't work try `py -m pip install us`. Make sure you are using command prompt and not using your IDEz[image]

As you can see it worked first try for me.

Comment: I get `'pip' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: @jvalenti do you have pip installed on your pc?

Comment: It's supposed to be installed via anaconda

Answer (score 1):

Since you have downloaded the files, Extract them in a folder and normally a setup.py file must be include, open command prompt in that folder and run :

```
python setup.py install
```